# Laravel 7 resource model binding, no information in the edit page

Tags: laravel, binding, laravel-7

In Laravel 7 I did the following:

```
php artisan make:controller ClientGroupController --resource --model=ClientGroup
```

I modified the `edit` function in `ClientGroupController` to look as follows:

```
public function edit(ClientGroup $clientGroup)
{
    return view('extranet.groups.create_modal_form', compact('clientGroup'));
}
```

I also added this route resource: `Route::resource('groups', 'ClientGroupController');`

A `dd($clientGroup)` in the view (when visiting the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/2/edit) yields none of the data for the current record (a blank `ClientGroup` object).

Did I miss a step? Why does `$clientGroup->id` return `null` in my view (id is the primary key of the `client_group` table).

Comment: Change `Route::resource('groups', 'ClientGroupController');` to `Route::resource('client_groups', 'ClientGroupController');`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter is there a way to override that behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel resource always return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328076/laravel-resource-always-return-null)

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function edit($id)
{
$clientGroup = ClientGroup::find($id);
    return view('extranet.groups.create_modal_form', compact('clientGroup'));
}
```

Comment: i'm aware of this method, but it is my understanding that the other should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with resource routes defined like this:

```
Route::resource('others', OtherServiceController::class);
```

But my model name was `OtherService`

This was my edit and update function

```
public function edit(OtherService $otherService)
{
    return view('others.master-edit', compact('otherService'));
}

public function update(OtherServiceRequest $request, OtherService $otherService)
{
    $otherService->update($request->validated());
    return redirect()->route('others.index')->withToastSuccess('Success Update Data');
}
```

But this code threw errors about a missing required parameter, because resource name and model name are not the same. So, my solution was to change the resource routes to match the model.

```
Route::resource('otherService', OtherServiceController::class);
```

Maybe you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328076/laravel-resource-always-return-null) question, marked answer tells about overriding

Comment: I'm sorry, i just want to comment but I dont have enough reputation. I clearly want to provide my code but I'm new with this community. Hope i can get as many assist with this forum.